# Using NLTK in C# via IronPython

Tags: c#, python, ironpython, nltk

I'm using Visual Studio 2010.  I have an IronPython console project and a C# console project.  This IronPython script works fine when I run it by itself:

```
import nltk

def Simple():
    baconIpsumFile = open('baconipsum.txt', 'r')
    baconIpsumCorpus = baconIpsumFile.read()

    tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(baconIpsumCorpus)
    text = nltk.Text(tokens)
    print text
```

Here is the C# console program, which does not work fine:

```
using IronPython.Hosting;

namespace IronNLTK.CSharp.Console
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var ipy = Python.CreateRuntime();
            dynamic test = ipy.UseFile("C:\\Path\\To\\Program.py");
            test.Simple();
        }
    }
}
```

I get an `ImportException: No module named nltk`.  What am I missing?

Comment: Can you interact with the `ipy` runtime and adjust the path there?

Comment: I've also tried that. I.e. the accepted answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371994/importing-external-module-in-ironpython

Answer (score 3):

sounds like you need to update sys.path to point to wherever NLTK lives.

check this out: [Importing external module in IronPython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371994/importing-external-module-in-ironpython)

Comment: if you mean something like sys.path.append(r"c:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython\Lib") that doesn't work either

Comment: Of course that does not work. Backslash is the string escape character. If you want to put a path in a Python string, then you need to do C:/Progr...  or C:\\Progr...

Comment: In addition, it is not unusual for portable software to have a problem with paths that contain spaces in the name. Have you tried installing another instance of IronPython in C:\IronPython so that you don't have any directories with space in the names?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I did use escaped backslashes, I'll look into the spaces in the path name though...

Answer (score 2):

Awesome news, Visual Studio 2017 is embedded with Anaconda’s Python distribution which has NTLK and other machine learning packages.