# How to integrate python library in c# project

Tags: c#, python

I started working with machine learning and found that a lot of codes are available in public.

Before I get involved deeply I would like to find out some way of incorporating Python codes into C # project.

Can anyone help me out in this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: See [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23129054/integration-of-python-in-c-sharp-application). The recommendation appears to be IronPython.

Comment: Thank you, nbryans. It also helped me a lot too.

Answer (score 6):

There's also [PythonNet](https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet) 
which has similar goals as IronPython but [is a different solution](http://pythonnet.github.io/).