# Iron Python packages

Tags: python, c#, ironpython

I tried use ironpython to run python script from c#. Without packages it work well. But when I use packages in python script like:

```
import pmdarima

# do something
```

I get error.

I tried add path location:

```
ICollection<string> searchPaths = engine.GetSearchPaths();
searchPaths.Add("/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages");
searchPaths.Add("/home/franta/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages");
engine.SetSearchPaths(searchPaths);
```

But I still get error - No module named 'fnmatch'. (Also tried install module fnmatch, but there is no module fnmatch???).

So my question is how to install packages to iron python? Or is something better then iron python?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importing external module in IronPython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371994/importing-external-module-in-ironpython)

Comment: No, still get same error.